# Can't execute login function. No errors

Tags: php, mysql, session

I've been looking at my code for days, but can't seem to find the problem. I'm new in PHP, so I'm not really familiar with all of it.

Below is my code. No errors. No registered session variable values.

**db-config.php**

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'mcsh';

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

**login.php**

```
<form id="user-login" action="index.php" method="POST">
    <h1>Administrator Login</h1>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required/>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
    <a href="/">Forgot your password?</a>
</form>

<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if (!empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    include("../config/db-config.php");

    $sql = "SELECT `userid`, `password` FROM users WHERE userid = '" . $username . "' AND userlevel = '99'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['userid'];
            header("Location: index.php");
            exit;
        }
        else {
        ?>
            <p class="msg" id="error">Invalid username or password. Please try again.</p>
        <?php
        }
    }
    else {
    ?>
        <p class="msg" id="error">Invalid username or password. Please try again.</p>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include("../config/config.php");
if (empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}
else {
//the rest of the index page...
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. This has many dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) since you didn’t [properly escape values](http://bobby-tables.com/php). This code allows *anyone* to get *anything* from your site. **DO NOT** write your own authentication system. Any [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in.

Comment: Thank you for the warnings. I know this login function is very unsecured. My only problem is that it doesn't do anything. Does not give me errors or such.

Comment: You can spend a lot of time debugging these things and still have a system that can't be trusted. I've written a lot of code and I still wouldn't trust myself to get this right, there's dozens of things you must do and dozens more you shouldn't. To learn PHP the right way, find a framework that fits your style and needs, then learn that. It will set you on the right track and give you a whole bunch of tools for debugging and testing.

Comment: As for this particular chunk of code, make sure you've turned on `mysqli` exceptions and trust nothing. Every SQL command can and will fail eventually, so you need to handle the failures properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form in login.php submits to index.php. In index.php, if the username is not yet in the session, you are redirected back to login.php. There you check `if (!empty($_POST)) {` at the beginning of your PHP code.

`$_POST` *will* be empty, because you have redirected to that page, not POSTed to it, so the PHP code will not be executed.

Remove the `action="index.php"` and that form will submit to itself (login.php). Also, move the HTML form code *below* the PHP code so that you will not have output before the redirect header if the login is successful.